# Content Security Policy sandbox to allow redirect with META

Tags: html, sandbox, content-security-policy

In my web app i allow users to download html files they uploaded.
I want to make this download to be maximum secure.

If users just open a html in new tab, it is insecure, there can be some script to catch cookies or so.

I added the header "Content-Security-Policy: sandbox" for such downloads. And it solves the problem.

But i got the problem with some subgroup of html files, which are "bookmarks". Files contain simple html like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Opening http://example.com</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://example.com">
</HEAD>
<BODY style="font-family:Tahoma;Arial;font-size:12px;padding:20px;color:#aaa">
Opening <b>http://example.com</b>...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

After it is opened in new tab, i need a user to be redirected to the host in the file.
It works without the header "Content-Security-Policy: sandbox" , but doen't work with it.

I tried different sandbox modes
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-scripts
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-top-navigation

But nothing allows to execute that redirect.

is there a way to do it?

Comment: I had the same problem, but now it works with `Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-scripts` . (Both in Firefox and Google Chrome)

Comment: Specification: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#sandboxing:sandboxed-automatic-features-browsing-context-flag